# How do I mcast multiple pcap files simultaneously with guaranteed ordering and controllable speed?

Tags: linux, multicast, pcap

We capture many pcap files every day on many different multicast groups.  For the purposes of testing & benchmarking, we wish to replay these files in an isolated environment and in a controlled way.  These pcap files are captured simultaneously, but on different multicast groups & ports.

I want to replay these files back on to the network (possibly with ttl=0 or 1) in the order in which the packets were recorded, and on different (and specifyable) multicast groups.  This ordering must be synchronized accross *all* of the files being played back.

For example, suppose we have two capture files, `foo.pcap` and `bar.pcap`.  We want to replay `foo.pcap` packets on mcast group 239.255.0.1:30001, and the `bar.pcap` packets should be replayed on 239.255.0.2:30002.

`foo.pcap` has packets recorded at time offsets 0, 1, and 5.  `bar.pcap` has packets recorded at time offsets (relative to `foo.pcap`) 3, 4, and 5.

So what I'm looking for is a way to replay these packets *in an order synchronized accross both `foo.pcap` and `bar.pcap`*.  In other words, the first 2 packets from `foo.pcap` should go out on to 239.255.0.1:30001, and then the first two packets from `bar.pcap` should go out on 239.255.0.2:30002, and then the last packet from `foo.pcap` should go out *at the same time* (or close to it) as the last packet from `bar.pcap`.

We also need to be able to tune the rate at which packets are replayed.  eg, at recorded speed; 10x recorded speed; 1 GB/sec; etc.

How can I accomplish this?

I have looked in to tools such as [tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/) and [bittwist](http://bittwist.sourceforge.net/doc/bittwist.1.html), but these tools either won't send on different groups, or won't synchronize the egress order across all the files.